# Default map fill color, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I am making a choropleth using ggplot2 with the county dataset. The data I am tying in to the county data is only for a handful of counties. My questions is: how can I change the default grey fill for the counties in which I don't have data? In the merged dataset there are just na's for the mapped values in the grey counties.

Code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(long, lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=`Surface Mines`), col="grey") +
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="yellow", high="red") +
  geom_path(data=state , colour="black") +
  theme_void()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Did you check out the `?scale_fill_continuous` help page? There is a `na.value=` parameter you can pass to set the missing color.

Comment: @MrFlick That'll do it- thanks! Put it down as an answer if you like and I'll mark it correct.